# How to use Coordinator pattern in Xcode 11/iOS13 on UIKit?

Tags: ios, swift, appdelegate, coordinator-pattern

I have been trying to learn the Coordinator pattern by creating a new app on Xcode 11.2 using Storyboards as Interface design.
I followed [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7HgbcTqxoN4&feature=em-uploademail) by Paul Hudson but I got stuck at minute 12 when code needed to be added to the AppDelegate.swift file. Like it is the app will launch, the first view controller will show but it will not navigate.
What should I change or, better, where should I move the present code to make it work?
Whole project can be found [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/41j3eaytb2kynxz/Coordinators.zip?dl=0).
In short the code that in iOS 12 and before was in AppDelegate is this:

```
var coordinator: MainCoordinator?
var window: UIWindow?

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    let navController = UINavigationController()
    coordinator = MainCoordinator(navigationController: navController)
    coordinator?.start()

    window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    window?.rootViewController = navController
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

    return true
}
```

I have seen that now `window` is in SceneDelegate but moving everything there to the sceneDidConnect method is not helping.
Can someone enlighten me here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So a few changes have to be made to be able to implement this pattern. Firstly, you should restore your `AppDelegate` to it's initial format on creation:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

You can remove the `var coordinator: MainCoordinator?` declaration at the top.

In `SceneDelegate` replace the code in the `sceneWillConnectToSession` function with the following:

```
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) { 
    guard let windowScene = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
    let navController = UINavigationController()
    let coordinator = MainCoordinator(navigationController: navController)
    coordinator.start()

    let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
    window.rootViewController = navController
    self.window = window
    window.makeKeyAndVisible()
}
```

The final change is that I removed the weak declaration for `MainCoordinator` in your view controllers.

So I just replaced it with `var coordinator: MainCoordinator?`, and then it worked.

[Reference Article: The Scene Delegate In Xcode 11 And iOS 13](https://learnappmaking.com/scene-delegate-app-delegate-xcode-11-ios-13/)

Comment: Have you tried to run the code? I applied your edits and it behaves exactly as before... I was already getting to the main screen but the buttons were not navigating...

Comment: Yes I'm sorry, I thought the issue was that no view controllers were loading for some reason. I found the issue with the code, it is that the UIWindow you are creating is never actually being made keyAndVisible. You can confirm this by checking the memory addresses of the VC created in the MainCoordinator vs the one that exists when you try to breakpoint one of the `@IBAction` functions. I will edit soon

Comment: Nice! It works! I just avoided `let` before `window` and the `self.window` part because SceneDelegate already has a `var window: UIWindow?`. Thanks!

Comment: This seems to be the closest I can get to a working solution in XCode 12 (oh how I hate XCode), when running with the basic skeleton I get the following warning in the console: `[WindowScene] Failed to instantiate the default view controller for UIMainStoryboardFile 'Main' - perhaps the designated entry point is not set? `

Comment: Can you add an Objective-C version of the function?